# Gets documents and total count of them in single query include pagination

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm new in mongo and use **mongodb aggregation framework** for my queries. I need to retrieve some records which satisfy certain conditions(**include pagination+sorting)** and also get **total count** of records.

Now, I perform next steps:

1. Create `$match` operator
   `{ "$match" : { "year" : "2012" , "author.authorName" : { "$regex" :
   "au" , "$options" : "i"}}}`
2. Added sorting and pagination
   `{ "$sort" : { "some_field" : -1}} , { "$limit" : 10} , { "$skip" : 0}`

After querying I receive the expected result: 10 documents with all fields.

For pagination I need to know the total count of records which satisfy these conditions, in my case 25.

I use next query to get count : `{ "$match" : { "year" : "2012" , "author.authorName" : { "$regex" : "au" , "$options" : "i"}}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$all" , "reviewsCount" : { "$sum" : 1}}} ,  { "$sort" : { "some_field" : -1}} , { "$limit" : 10} , { "$skip" : 0}`

But I don't want to perform **two separate queries**: one for retrieving documents and second for total counts of records which satisfy certain conditions.

I want do it in one **single query** and get result in next format:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
            "my_documets": [
                        {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("512f1f47a411dc06281d98c0"),
                        "author" : {
                                "authorName" : "author name1",
                                "email" : "email1@email.com"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("512f1f47a411dc06281d98c0"),
                        "author" : {
                                "authorName" : "author name2",
                                "email" : "email2@email.com"
                            }
                        }, .......

                    ],
                    "total" : 25
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I tried modify the group operator :   `{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$all" , "author" : "$author"  "reviewsCount" : { "$sum" : 1}}}` 
But in this case I got : "**exception: the group aggregate field 'author' must be defined as an expression inside an object**". If add all fields in _id  then reviewsCount always = 1 because all records are different.

Nobody know how it can be implement in single query ? Maybe mongodb has some features or operators for this case? Implementation with using two separate query reduces performance for querying thousand or millions records. In my application it's very critical performance  issue.

I've been working on this all day and haven't been able to find a solution, so thought i'd turn to the stackoverflow community.

Thanks.

Comment: You asked this on MongoDB users group so I posted the answer there - that medium is better for discussion anyway since SO is more for Q&A and this isn't a clearcut use case.

Comment: If i correctly understood you there is an ability do it in single query. Can you give some example ? You propose use two different queries instead of one single. But I want create two implementations (with one single and two different queries) to determine which of them will run faster. How I said a performance issues very critical for my application and if single query will works more faster then two different I will use the first case.  If I wrong in my reasoning, please give me more information for investigation.

Comment: full post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/5AlOJATYq2I

Comment: please ask your follow-up on the mailing list. it's impossible to have long discussions of anything on SO.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using $facet in the aggregation pipeline as

```
db.name.aggregate([
{$match:{your match criteria}},
{$facet: {
       data: [{$sort: sort},{$skip:skip},{$limit: limit}],
       count:[{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}]
}}
])
```

In data, you'll get your list with pagination and in the count, count variable will have a total count of matched documents.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have one example, but I think it's really crazy query, I put it only for fun, but if this example faster than 2 query, tell us about it in the comments please.

For this question i create collection called "so", and put into this collection 25 documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512fa86cd99d0adda2a744cd"),
    "authorName" : "author name1",
    "email" : "email1@email.com",
    "c" : 1
}
```

My query use aggregation framework:

```
db.so.aggregate([
    { $group:
        { 
            _id: 1, 
            collection: { $push : { "_id": "$_id", "authorName": "$authorName", "email": "$email", "c": "$c" } }, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: 
        "$collection"
    },
    { $project: 
        { "_id": "$collection._id", "authorName": "$collection.authorName", "email": "$collection.email", "c": "$collection.c", "count": "$count" }
    },
    { $match: 
        { c: { $lte: 10 } } 
    },
    { $sort : 
        { c: -1 }
    },
    { $skip:
        2
    },
    { $limit:
        3
    },
    { $group: 
        { 
            _id: "$count", 
            my_documets: { 
                $push: {"_id": "$_id", "authorName":"$authorName", "email":"$email", "c":"$c" } 
            } 
        } 
    },
    { $project: 
        { "_id": 0, "my_documets": "$my_documets", "total": "$_id" }
    }
])
```

Result for this query:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "my_documets" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("512fa900d99d0adda2a744d4"),
                    "authorName" : "author name8",
                    "email" : "email8@email.com",
                    "c" : 8
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("512fa900d99d0adda2a744d3"),
                    "authorName" : "author name7",
                    "email" : "email7@email.com",
                    "c" : 7
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("512fa900d99d0adda2a744d2"),
                    "authorName" : "author name6",
                    "email" : "email6@email.com",
                    "c" : 6
                }
            ],
            "total" : 25
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

By the end, I think that for big collection 2 query (first for data, second for count) works faster. For example, you can count total for collection like this:

```
db.so.count()
```

or like this:

```
db.so.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).count()
```

I don't fully sure in first example, but in second example we use only cursor, which means higher speed:

```
db.so.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_ reverse",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 25,
    "nscannedObjects" : 25,
    "nscanned" : 25,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 25,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 25,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    !!!!!>>>  "indexOnly" : true, <<<!!!!!
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works and is useful for me to get matched documents when using pagination. This is quicker than performing all the Regex tests twice.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (full discussion was on the [MongoDB Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/5AlOJATYq2I/discussion)) here is the aggregation you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate(db.docs.aggregate( [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "year" : "2012"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null,
            "my_documents" : {
                "$push" : {
                    "_id" : "$_id",
                    "year" : "$year",
                    "author" : "$author"
                }
            },
            "reviewsCount" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : 0,
            "my_documents" : 1,
            "total" : "$reviewsCount"
        }
    }
] )
```

By the way, you don't need aggregation framework here - you can just use a regular find.  You can get count() from a cursor without having to re-query.

Comment: Can you give some example for regular find and cursor count w/o having to re-query?

Comment: try this at the shell prompt  > var cursor = db.collection.find({condition}).sort().skip().limit();  > cursor.count();  > cursor.toArray();

Comment: but this cursor contains only documents that finded by {condition}, and cursor.count() returns counts in dataset, not full count of documents in collection! This approach not work for this task!

Comment: Read the original post: "For pagination i need to know a total counts of records which satisfy this conditions. in my case 25" - which satisfy this conditions means not the total count for the collection but the total count of this query.

Comment: btw, did you really downvote my answer because *you* misread the question? mighty big of you...

Comment: In response, I started from my own experience.